# how to show website with full width on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

Here is one website which is not responsive but it accommodate full width of mobile screen. 
http://www.tones.be  (try to open on mobile device then you will understand what i mean. it don't have horizontal scroll bar and it is zoom in version of desktop website).
I also want to build similar website but unable to figure out how to do so. I know how to use media query for handling screen size. 
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried using `width: 100%;` in your CSS? That should make the width the same as the screen regardless of mobile/desktop.

Comment: Most browsers on phones will auto zoom to the required amount without scroll bars. That site isn't using any meta="viewport" tags.

Comment: should i  remove viewport tag

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the meta tag in the head

```
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = no">
</head>
```

Comment: Does this still allow user to zoom in on mobile?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can't zoom in or out if using this.

Answer (score 7):

You could try to add this in your page head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will attempt to make the browser display the page at full-width.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS code, then someone should be able to figure this out for you.

Comment: @TechHelp Have you got it worked? If yes what change did you make?

Comment: This only used about 2/3 of the width of my mobile screen, too much white space too right...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution. It worked for me.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=0" />
```

Comment: Links are really small and unreadable for me after using this and no zoom possible

Answer (score 0):

I've found that

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0" />
```

works for me. It loads the page zoomed completely out but lets the user zoom in if they struggle to read the text.